# Assistance to rebase and merge

Tags: git, github

I've branched from `development` into `<working-branch>`, made some changes and committed everything back to `<working-branch>`at GitHub. Made a pull request on GitHub, code reviewed, approved, all that jazz. Now for some reason, which I'm too junior to be allowed to question, they don't want to use GitHub to do the merge, instead they want to use `git` on the command line and do something like this:

- all the commits combined into a single "clean" commit
- make sure the commit is tagged as `<working-branch>` (I think it's currently "Made requested fixes.")
- merge that commit into `development`

I SSHed into my working repository and executed the following, including the output from `git`. I've had to anonymize any identifying information.

Right off, I'm not sure if what I've done is right. This is my best guess based on some conflicting documentation I was given.

When I did `git rebase -i origin/<working-branch>` it just gave me one non-comment line `noop` which isn't what I was expecting. I was expecting a list of all the commits I've made. I wanted to stop there, but when I did `:q` in the editor, it just went on and rebased, and didn't give me an option to abort.

```
$ git checkout origin/<working-branch>
Note: checking out 'origin/<working-branch>'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at <hash> Made requested fixes.

$ git rebase -i origin/<working-branch>
Successfully rebased and updated detached HEAD.

$ git merge
fatal: No current branch.

$ git status
HEAD detached at origin/<working-branch>
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The last two results with "fatal", "HEAD detached", and "nothing to commit" look scary. I don't know what they mean and I hope I haven't corrupted the repository. Can anyone help undo this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To un-detach:

```
git checkout working-branch
```

The `noop` was because you rebased on your own branch. To rebase off the develop branch:

```
git fetch
git rebase -i origin/develop
```

It will give you a text editor view of your commits. If you want to squash them into a single clean commit change `pick` to `s` for all but the first line. Save and quit the file and you will be given a text editor screen to write the commit message (for each commit). Save and quit and the rebasing is over.

If the rebasing says there were conflicts you can undo it:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Then Google how to resolve conflicts :)

If it worked you will have to push with:

```
git push --force
```

Warning: force pushing overwrites what is on the remote server, it is a destructive operation. Make sure you are definitely on your working branch.